# Calculate new pitch and roll after rotating about the z axis

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, circles, rotations

I am wanting to know how to find out the new pitch and roll values when rotating around a circle. I have become a little stuck on how to achieve this, but hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

I currently have a circular plate (Yellow in the Picture) that has a specific pitch, roll and heading applied to it. I can work out the overall tilt (blue dot) by taking the pitch vector and the roll vector, using Pythagoras work out the tilt.

Then using Atan, I can find out the bearing to the blue dot.

I then will turn through a specified angle to reach the red dot.

I am struggling to find out how to find out the tilt on the plate at the red dot and how to split that back into the correct pitch and roll vectors?

[image: Plate Tilt]